# Platypus error: script missing from application bundle

Tags: ruby, scripting, platypus

My use-case was converting a ruby application into an executable app on a mac. When I created a release on github ... meaning users would download the project as a zip and run the program.

```
error message: script missing from application bundle
```

I had all checkboxes selected when creating application as shown:[image]

I put my answer below. This was a quick solution. However, may not be best practice. If anyone puts forth a better answer  determined by the community. I will make that the answer. The answer to this question regarding a ruby script should work for other scripts Platypus turns into .app's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, after app is created;

```
right click .app file
select "show package" contents
navigate to path ...
Contents -> Resources

copy the script that you linked to ... in my case it was a ruby script.rb
delete the script alias names "script"
rename your copied script "script" without the .rb extension.

now since the script is inside the app 
it will no longer have an issue finding the script location.
```